# function create button with a passing argument onclick function

Tags: javascript

Can someone explain me like i'm five why is it executing the function without the click event. And how to fix it. Thanks.

```
function test(){
    alert("works");
}

function createButton(name,location,id,funX){
    var button = document.createElement("input");
    button.type = "submit";
    button.name = name;
    button.id = id;
    button.onclick = funX;
    var placeHolder = document.getElementById(location);
    placeHolder.appendChild(button);
};



window.onload = function () {
    createButton("Submit","content","submitEnd",test());
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mabui91/yLoty39s/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add parenthesis to a function, you call it. Not later, but right then and there, and you return what ever the function returns.

A function in javascript returns `undefined` by default, unless you explicitly return something else.

What you're really writing is

```
createButton("Submit", "content", "submitEnd", undefined);
```

The last `undefined` is because you called the function, it would be the same as

```
var result = test(); // undefined

createButton("Submit", "content", "submitEnd", result);
```

The way to solve it, is to **reference** the function, not call it

```
createButton("Submit", "content", "submitEnd", test);
```

See, no parenthesis.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/yLoty39s/1/)

Comment: You should consider a career in education.

Comment: The best things in life are!